# Have a question concerning Http and Https and Images

Tags: c#, http, https, next.js

When I used Nextjs Client with http and C# Api with Http, I can make the client show the images which is saved in the virtual directory. But when I upgrade my nextjs to Https, the images do not show anymore. As I see in F12 in client, all of my image path was converted to have https. Eg: http://domain.info/images/filename.jpg was converted to https://domain.info/images/filename.jpg

I use IIS Window Server to upload my code.

My image code:

```
{logoData ?
        <div className="logo">
            <img className="img-fluid" src= 
{BaseGatewayImage + logoData.imagePath} alt="Newsprk" data-lazy-src= 
{BaseGatewayImage + logoData.imagePath} />
       </div> : <></>}
```

this is the images after https:

[Images after https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POOOG.png)

Can some one help me with this case? Do I have to upgrade my api to https?

Comment: Usually JavaScript doesn't behave any different whether your backend requires HTTPS or not. What do you mean by "the images do not show"? When pressing F12 can you see the image in the "Response" tab? Please provide the piece of code used to "show" the images.

Comment: The common usecase is to build up a simple nginx proxy to pass data from https requests to locally running http api. It makes things easier when setting up https certificates and routing requests to different apis using nginx

Comment: @DarkTwister I used IIS, not nginx

Comment: @JamesRhodes are you getting any errors in the devloper console (F12)? I might have misread your question... if you're trying to access the image at an HTTPS address but you haven't upgraded your backend/API, then that's probably the issue yes.